# ASP.Net MVC Posted form values not mapping back onto viewmodel in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My ViewModel is:

```
public class ObjectiveVM
{
    public string DateSelected { get; set; }
    public List<string> DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public IList<ObList> obList { get; set; }
    public class ObList
    {
        public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public int AnalystId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AnalystName { get; set; }
        public bool Include { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is passed to the view, populated as expected - and displays correctly in the view.

My problem is when it is posted back to the controller.  My controller code to accept it back is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Analyst(ObjectiveVM ovm)
```

`ovm.obList` is always showing as null:

[image: Showing posted values]

My View html is:

```
@model Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Analyst";
}
<h2>Copy Objectives for Analyst</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Objective</legend>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DateSelected, new SelectList(Model.DatePeriod))
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.obList[0].Include)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.obList[0].AnalystName)
    </th>
     <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.obList[0].Title)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.obList[0].Description)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var obList in Model.obList)
{
    <tr>
       <td>

            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obList.ObjectiveId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obList.AnalystId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obList.Title)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => obList.Description)

            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => obList.Include)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obList.AnalystName)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obList.Title) 
         </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => obList.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Copy Selected Objectives" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

    }

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Looking in Developer Tools at the Posted form values, they appear to be ok:
[image: Developer Tools]

Can anyone see any reason the posted form values, are not mapping back onto my viewmodel in the Controller HTTP post?

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `for...loop` here, not a `foreach....loop`.

```
@for (int idx = 0;idx < Model.obList.Count;idx++){
    @Html.HiddenFor(_ => Model.obList[idx].ObjectiveId)

    // ... etc....

}
```

Without the indexer (`idx`), the model binder will not know how to bind the values back to the right collection item.

Comment: Thank you - on the first @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => obList[idx].Include) however, I get the error: The name 'obList' does not exist in the current context - thanks, Mark

Comment: Ignore me - I added Model. in and it's working now - thank you very much, also to Chris Hardie.  Mark

Answer (score 1):

When working with collections in my views, I typically write out my markup without the use of helpers:

```
@for (int i = 0;i < Model.obList.Count();i++){
     <input type="hidden" name="ObList[@i].ObjectiveId" id="ObList[@i].ObjectiveId" value="@ObList[i].ObjectiveId" />
     <input type="hidden" name="ObList[@i].AnalystId" id="ObList[@i].AnalystId" value="@ObList[i].AnalystId" />
     ...
}
```

This will conform to the wire format the model binder expects, and will slot your values into your ViewModel: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx